# Embedding a flash object old SWF markup? Will this work?

Tags: html, flash, embed, markup, swfobject

I am embedding a flash object into my site and when I do I get a message from dreamweaver saying

"This page contains some swf objects that may not work correctly in the most recent versions of Internet Explorer. Dreamweaver cannot convert them to the new SWF markups please delete each of them and insert them again"

I am not aware of any new SWF markups but here is my code to check maybe I am doing something wrong:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>

<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="350" height="140" title="Flash Audio Recorder">
<param name="movie" value="AudioRecorder.swf" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="userid=2&settings=myXML/settings.xml" />
<embed src="AudioRecorder.swf" FlashVars="userid=2&settings=myXML/settings.xml" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="350" height="140"></embed>
</object>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it in a browser - if it works its ok - Dreamweaver is rubbish!

Comment: My experience with Dreamweaver heads back about 9 years and is horrific as well. Screwed up all my DHTML templates and without a backup and version management I had to start over. Absolute madness.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) and you don't have to worry about stuff like that. Makes it all happen in the blink of an eye cross-platform.